# Why Everyone should leave hometown before the lamp off?

Tags: belief

During Pedha Karma, Why Everyone should leave hometown before the lamp off?

For example: There is a family, Mother died, After few days family conducted 
Pedha Karma. The Sons & Daughters, who are living abroad came & participate in Pedha Karma. They put main lamp in the house.  Now They should leave hometown before lamp turns off.

Why like that ?